# Django Rest Framework Reversing URL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two files, one containing the URL like this

```
url(r'^users/', include('api_manager.users_urls', namespace='user'))
```

in second URL file i have this:

```
url(r'^', users_views.UsersList.as_view(), name='index')
```

When i hit the URL localhost:8000/api/users/ It redirect me to view 'UserList' and here i am using reverse function

```
reverse("user:index")
```

it returns me the /apiusers/ instead of /api/users/

Please let me know what is wrong in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, i find out that i am using `api/*` in my parent URL file, i just remove the '*' and reverse function returning the `/api/users/`

:)